# Do I ALWAYS need to use AsyncTask when using MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql

Hi guys I have a question about Asyntask which is used in android studio :

As far as I know AynTask is used for user interface via one thread, the so called UI Thread. If you perform a long running operation directly on the UI Thread, for example downloading a file from the internet, the user interface of your application will “freeze” until the corresponding task is finished.

But let's say that I want to register an account so that I can login, that shouldnt take time at all so why should I use Asyntask for this?

Let's say I want to send 100 strings to the Database, that can be done in milisecs I think, so again, why to use and how to decide when to use Asyntask?

I hope you guys can help me out, I have been searching for a long time !

Comment: No you don't have to. You should use it only when there is a need to like performing network operations or querying large data sets and so on. but for the user registration for example, you can't guarantee that it won't take too much time, as the internet connection may be too slow to perform the registration

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how much time operation will take, you should perform it in a separate thread and then pass the results to UI thread. I think the database should be accessed in a separate thread as well as HTTP requests. In the case of time-consuming query, it may be a long operation. AsyncTask is one way to do it. You can also use other techniques. The popular technique used nowadays is applying [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) library, which gives you the high-level functional reactive interface for writing multi-threaded applications with a few additional features. You can perform an operation in e.g. `Sechdulers.io()` (I/O) thread and then pass the result to `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, which is UI thread.

There are also other techniques like using [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) & [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) from Android SDK or using [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class from Java, but such techniques require more knowledge, more work, writing more boilerplate code & you have more problems to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !